# Finding an Orthogonal Vector to v=4i—j+k

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

Assuming **v=4i−j+k** and **w=2i+3j−k**.

Find a scalar *s* such that **v** is orthogonal to **v—** s**w**

Okay, so I know that two vectors are orthogonal when the dot product is 0. Or **v** •  (**v—** s**w**) **=0**

What strategy would you use to solve this? I feel like this is probably a very simple question, but I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: $\mathbb{v} \cdot (\mathbb{v} - s\mathbb{w})$ is an equation with $s$ as an unknown. Solve that equation, it is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbf{v}\cdot(\mathbf{v}-s\mathbf{w})=0$$
$$|\mathbf{v}|^2-(\mathbf{v}.\mathbf{w})s=0$$
$$|\mathbf{v}|^2-(\mathbf{v}.\mathbf{w})s=0$$
$$s=\frac{|\mathbf{v}|^2}{(\mathbf{v}.\mathbf{w})}=\frac{16+1+1}{8-3-1}$$